# Load content page after master control event is raised

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page in `asp.Net` and some content pages children of the master page.
In master page I have a `Drop Down` control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="languageSelect" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="seletedLanguageChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="English">English</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="French">French</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And in master page code behind:

```
public void seletedLanguageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Add(Settings.LanguageParameters.LanguageParams, languageSelect.SelectedValue);
}
```

Now in Home page, I am checking the drop down value and based on it I am rendering the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    {
        Session.Add(Settings.LanguageParameters.LanguageParams, "English");
    }
    string language = Session["LanguageParams"].ToString();
    if (language == "English")
    {
        englishTable.Style.Add("display", "normal");
        frenchTable.Style.Add("display", "none");   
     }
     else
     {
         frenchTable.Style.Add("display", "normal");
         englishTable.Style.Add("display", "none");
     }
}
```

The problem is that when I change the drop down selection (eg: from "English" to "French"), Home `Page_Load` method is being executed before the `seletedLanguageChanged` is fired which is causing the Home page to execute the `if (language == "English")` part and then `seletedLanguageChanged` is fired.

How Can I prevent Home `Page_Load` method to execute before `seletedLanguageChanged` is fired?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. What you can do is to move the logic to `OnPreRender` event which does happen after Page_Load and after control events (like `OnSelectedIndexChanged`). So clean up your `Page_Load` and use this instead:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnPreRender(e);
  if (!IsPostBack) 
  {
      Session.Add(Settings.LanguageParameters.LanguageParams, "English");
  }
  string language = Session["LanguageParams"].ToString();
  if (language == "English")
  {
      englishTable.Style.Add("display", "normal");
      frenchTable.Style.Add("display", "none");   
   }
   else
   {
       frenchTable.Style.Add("display", "normal");
       englishTable.Style.Add("display", "none");
   }
}
```